# Getting map coordinates from Leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to use Leaflet to get the map coordinates of somewhere a user has right clicked. I've been going through the Leaflet API and so far I've figured out that I need to listen to the `contextmenu` event and use `mouseEventToLatLng` [method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-mouseeventtolatlng) to get the coordinates when clicked. However, when I go through and debug my code I'm not seeing an accessible latLng variable anywhere. Did I miss understand something in the API?

```
function setMarkers() {
        document.getElementById("transitmap").addEventListener("contextmenu", function( event ) {
            // Prevent the browser's context menu from appearing
            event.preventDefault();

            var coords = L.mouseEventToLatLng( event );
        });
    };
```

Comment: What you want is to make "coords" variable accesible from everywhere?

Comment: Actually, I'm wating to access coords from within that function. The issue is when I run the code the console gives me an error message saying `mouseEventToLatLng is not defined`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you want to get is [mousemove](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-mousemove) event. This is basically how you do it,

```
var lat, lng;

map.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
   lat = ev.latlng.lat;
   lng = ev.latlng.lng;
});

document.getElementById("transitmap").addEventListener("contextmenu", function (event) {
    // Prevent the browser's context menu from appearing
    event.preventDefault();

    // Add marker
    // L.marker([lat, lng], ....).addTo(map);
    alert(lat + ' - ' + lng);

    return false; // To disable default popup.
});
```

Comment: But one of my use cases is to set the marker by right clicking on the map that way I can still use the left click to move the map around. If I use mousemove then it'll continuously be resetting the marker as the mouse moves around the map. Did I misunderstand something about your snippet?

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted The map's `mousemove` event won't continuously be resetting the marker. You can also still use left click to move the map around. What this basically does, is to capture where your cursor on the map is and translate it to `latlng`. Then, when you right-click on the map, it should only create the marker where that `latlng` is..

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!

Comment: Sadly this no longer seems to work on Leaflet 1.7.1

Answer (score 13):

The coordinates of the right click event should be directly available as [`latlng` property](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events-latlng) of the `event` argument of the `"contextmenu"` listener.

```js
map.on("contextmenu", function (event) {
  console.log("Coordinates: " + event.latlng.toString());
  L.marker(event.latlng).addTo(map);
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/9vm81YsQxnkAFs35N8Jo?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Martin: seems to be working fine with Leaflet v1.7.1 http://plnkr.co/edit/aCkd7oosk2cBS62u

Comment: @ghybs sorry this comment was for the above answer code, not sure how that managed to appear on your answer as well. I'd actually previously already upvoted this answer, too `:-)`